# How to change my default storage location for play store on samsung J1?

Tags: sd-card, samsung-galaxy-j1

I have tried searching through the whole settings list and 'my files' for the settings I have been told would be there, but I just can't find them. Please help.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're trying to achieve. What "default storage location" you are talking of?

Comment: @Izzy I think he meant the location to which all new apps will installed. From the factory setting it's set to internal storage ( around 4 GB), but we want to change this to set it to the external memory, the so-called SD card. I hope you got the point.

Comment: @AlFagera Indeed, that sounds reasonable. There is one answer pointing to an on-device setting. If that's not there, ADB might help: `adb shell pm set-install-location 2`.

Answer (score 1):

In Android ... Go to settings, Apps and press menu to select options, I think it's even called default storage location !...   Some devices dont have the option ... You need a app like Apps2Sd